# Putting a graphic in the background of the title line of poster?

Tags: diagrams, titles, backgrounds, posters, a0poster

I am using the `beamerposter.sty` file to make my poster and I want to put a background in the title section of the poster- not a graphic or logo of an institution, but an actual background that spans the entire length of the poster title.

I have been searching but I can't seem to find anything that specifically addresses this issue. I have the eso-pic, background, and wallpaper packages so if you can provide a solution with any of those I'd be grateful. Here is an example of what I mean to accomplish

[image: The poster has a blue background with a shell. I'd like to know how to do this in LaTeX (not necessarily with the same graphic)]

Here is the skeleton of my poster

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage[scale = 1]{beamerposter}
\usepackage{empheq}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usetheme{confposter}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black,bg=white} % Colors of the block titles
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=white} % Colors of the body of blocks
\setbeamercolor{block alerted title}{fg=white,bg=dblue!53} % Colors of the highlighted block titles
\setbeamercolor{block alerted body}{fg=black,bg=dblue!11} % Colors of the body of highlighted blocks
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Define the column widths and overall poster size
% To set effective sepwid, onecolwid and twocolwid values, first choose how many columns you want and how much separation you want between columns
% In this template, the separation width chosen is 0.024 of the paper width and a 4-column layout
% onecolwid should therefore be (1-(# of columns+1)*sepwid)/# of columns e.g. (1-(4+1)*0.024)/4 = 0.22
% Set twocolwid to be (2*onecolwid)+sepwid = 0.464
% Set threecolwid to be (3*onecolwid)+2*sepwid = 0.708
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newlength{\sepwid}
\newlength{\onecolwid}
\newlength{\twocolwid}
\newlength{\threecolwid}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}%
\setlength{\paperwidth}{48in} % A0 width: 46.8in
\setlength{\paperheight}{36in} % A0 height: 33.1in
\setlength{\sepwid}{0.024\paperwidth} % Separation width (white space) between columns
\setlength{\onecolwid}{0.22\paperwidth} % Width of one column
\setlength{\twocolwid}{0.464\paperwidth} % Width of two columns
\setlength{\threecolwid}{0.708\paperwidth} % Width of three columns
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in} % Reduce the top margin size
\newcommand*\widefcolorbox[1]{\setlength\fboxrule{0.8pt}\fcolorbox{Black}{dblue!10}{\hspace{1em}#1\hspace{1em}}}
\newcommand{\ip}{\hfill\\}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{graphicx}  % Required for including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for tables
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\title{Title} % Poster title

\author{a \inst{1} \and b \inst{1}  \and c\inst{1} \inst{2} \and d\inst{1}} % Author(s)

\institute{\inst{1} University \and \inst{2} Other University}


\begin{document}
\addtobeamertemplate{block end}{}{\vspace*{0.5ex}} % White space under blocks
\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted end}{}{\vspace*{2ex}} % White space under highlighted (alert) blocks
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0.5ex} % White space under figures
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{2ex} % White space under equations
\begin{frame}[t] % The whole poster is enclosed in one beamer frame
    \begin{columns}[t] % The whole poster consists of three major columns, the second of which is split into two columns twice - the [t] option aligns each column's content to the top
        \begin{column}{\sepwid}\end{column} % Empty spacer column
            \begin{column}{\onecolwid} % The first column
                \begin{block}{Abstract}             
                \end{block}
                \begin{block}{Introduction}
                \end{block}
                \begin{block}{Compound and Substrate}
                \end{block}
            \end{column} % End of the first column
            \begin{column}{\sepwid}\end{column}
                \begin{column}{\twocolwid} % Begin a column which is two columns wide (column 2)
                    \begin{columns}[t,totalwidth=\twocolwid] % Split up the two columns wide column
                        \begin{column}{\onecolwid}\vspace{-.6in} % The first column within column 2 (column 2.1)
                        \begin{block}{Compound and Substrate}
                        \end{block}
                        \begin{block}{Experimental Set-up}
                        \end{block}
                        \begin{block}{Results and Analysis}
                        \end{block}
                        \end{column} % End of column 2.1
                        \begin{column}{\onecolwid}\vspace{-.6in} % The second column within column 2 (column 2.2)
                            \begin{column}{\sepwid}\end{column}
                                \begin{block}{Results and Analysis}
                            \end{block}     
                            \end{column} % End of column 2.2
                        \end{columns} % End of the split of column 2 - any content after this will now take up 2 columns width
                    \end{column} % End of the second column
                    \begin{column}{\sepwid}\end{column}
                        \begin{column}{\onecolwid} % The third column
                            \begin{block}{Conclusion}
                            \end{block}
                            \begin{block}{References}
                            \end{block}
            \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=dblue,bg=white} % Change the block title color
                            \begin{block}{Acknowledgments}
                            \end{block}
                        \end{column} % End of the third column
                    \end{columns} % End of all the columns in the poster
                \end{frame} % End of the enclosing frame
\end{document}
```

I do not intend on using the provided picture but the idea is identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you will be satisfied with this solution. I just modified the header definition from the `confposter` package. I don't know how to determine the real height of the title, so it will be necessary to manually adjust the size of the background picture. Besides, I'm not familiar with `tikz` package and I assume that there may be a better solution. I used "*scope fading*" to improve the transition to poster text. It has a side effect:  this option reduce the width of the picture. Therefore, I added the parameter "*scale=1.01*". "*fig*" is the name of any picture for the header background.

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage[scale = 1]{beamerposter}
\usepackage{empheq}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usetheme{confposter}

% VAK redefine header template:
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[scale=1.01, opacity=0.99, xshift=0cm, yshift=-5.5cm,scope fading=south] at (current page.north){\pgfimage[width=\paperwidth,height=11cm]{fig}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\leavevmode
\begin{columns}
   \begin{column}{\linewidth}
    \vskip1cm
    \centering
    \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\color{jblue}\Huge{\textbf{\inserttitle}}\\[0.5ex]}
    \usebeamercolor{author in headline}{\color{fg}\Large{\insertauthor}\\[1ex]}
    \usebeamercolor{institute in headline}{\color{fg}\large{\insertinstitute}\\[1ex]}
    \vskip1cm
   \end{column}
   \vspace{1cm}
 \end{columns}
 \vspace{0.5in}
 \hspace{0.5in}\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=47in,colsep=0.15cm]{cboxb}\end{beamercolorbox}
 \vspace{0.1in}
}
% end of VAK definition



\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=black,bg=white} % Colors of the block titles
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=white} % Colors of the body of blocks
\setbeamercolor{block alerted title}{fg=white,bg=dblue!53} % Colors of the highlighted block titles
\setbeamercolor{block alerted body}{fg=black,bg=dblue!11} % Colors of the body of highlighted blocks
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Define the column widths and overall poster size
% To set effective sepwid, onecolwid and twocolwid values, first choose how many columns you want and how much separation you want between columns
% In this template, the separation width chosen is 0.024 of the paper width and a 4-column layout
% onecolwid should therefore be (1-(# of columns+1)*sepwid)/# of columns e.g. (1-(4+1)*0.024)/4 = 0.22
% Set twocolwid to be (2*onecolwid)+sepwid = 0.464
% Set threecolwid to be (3*onecolwid)+2*sepwid = 0.708
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newlength{\sepwid}
\newlength{\onecolwid}
\newlength{\twocolwid}
\newlength{\threecolwid}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}%
\setlength{\paperwidth}{48in} % A0 width: 46.8in
\setlength{\paperheight}{36in} % A0 height: 33.1in
\setlength{\sepwid}{0.024\paperwidth} % Separation width (white space) between columns
\setlength{\onecolwid}{0.22\paperwidth} % Width of one column
\setlength{\twocolwid}{0.464\paperwidth} % Width of two columns
\setlength{\threecolwid}{0.708\paperwidth} % Width of three columns
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in} % Reduce the top margin size
\newcommand*\widefcolorbox[1]{\setlength\fboxrule{0.8pt}\fcolorbox{Black}{dblue!10}{\hspace{1em}#1\hspace{1em}}}
\newcommand{\ip}{\hfill\\}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{graphicx}  % Required for including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for tables
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\title{Some Title} % Poster title

\author{a \inst{1} \and b \inst{1}  \and c\inst{1} \inst{2} \and d\inst{1}} % Author(s)

\institute{\inst{1} University \and \inst{2} Other University}


\begin{document}
\addtobeamertemplate{block end}{}{\vspace*{0.5ex}} % White space under blocks
\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted end}{}{\vspace*{2ex}} % White space under highlighted (alert) blocks
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0.5ex} % White space under figures
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{2ex} % White space under equations
\begin{frame}[t] % The whole poster is enclosed in one beamer frame
    \begin{columns}[t] % The whole poster consists of three major columns, the second of which is split into two columns twice - the [t] option aligns each column's content to the top
        \begin{column}{\sepwid}\end{column} % Empty spacer column
            \begin{column}{\onecolwid} % The first column
                \begin{block}{Abstract}             
                \end{block}
                \begin{block}{Introduction}
                \end{block}
                \begin{block}{Compound and Substrate}
                \end{block}
            \end{column} % End of the first column
            \begin{column}{\sepwid}\end{column}
                \begin{column}{\twocolwid} % Begin a column which is two columns wide (column 2)
                    \begin{columns}[t,totalwidth=\twocolwid] % Split up the two columns wide column
                        \begin{column}{\onecolwid}\vspace{-.6in} % The first column within column 2 (column 2.1)
                        \begin{block}{Compound and Substrate}
                        \end{block}
                        \begin{block}{Experimental Set-up}
                        \end{block}
                        \begin{block}{Results and Analysis}
                        \end{block}
                        \end{column} % End of column 2.1
                        \begin{column}{\onecolwid}\vspace{-.6in} % The second column within column 2 (column 2.2)
                            \begin{column}{\sepwid}\end{column}
                                \begin{block}{Results and Analysis}
                            \end{block}     
                            \end{column} % End of column 2.2
                        \end{columns} % End of the split of column 2 - any content after this will now take up 2 columns width
                    \end{column} % End of the second column
                    \begin{column}{\sepwid}\end{column}
                        \begin{column}{\onecolwid} % The third column
                            \begin{block}{Conclusion}
                            \end{block}
                            \begin{block}{References}
                            \end{block}
            \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=dblue,bg=white} % Change the block title color
                            \begin{block}{Acknowledgments}
                            \end{block}
                        \end{column} % End of the third column
                    \end{columns} % End of all the columns in the poster
                \end{frame} % End of the enclosing frame
\end{document}
```

The result is shown in the picture below:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! So I have applied your edit with a placeholder picture of mine and everything compiles with no errors but I do not see the placeholder picture that I am using. It may just be a question of picture size and position.

Did you have a file name for 'fig' like 'placeholder.png' or 'placeholder'?

Comment: I'm sorry, when I was formatting the text apparently removed some of the options of the environment 'tikzpicture'. The correct title should be '\begin{tikzpicture}[**remember picture,** overlay]'. I have already corrected this error in my answer.

Comment: @TO4991, In fact, the file name was 'fig.png'. And pdflatex should find the appropriate file.